# Accessing applet code from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I am unable to access the applet from my local. I m getting the below exception

java.lang.Exception: FILELOCATIONGENR:java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.dir read)

I tried to edit the java.policy file also, but still no use. your help will be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do: accessing your applet's method from a JSP page? Doing something in your applet? Please be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for that is using JavaScript. Assuming that you've the following method in the Applet class

```
public String getFoo() {
    return "foo";
}
```

and the Applet is embedded in JSP as follows

```
<applet name="appletname" ...>
```

then you can access it in JS as follows

```
var foo = document.appletname.getFoo();
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Applets - Invoking Applet methods from JavaScript](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html)

---

The exception which you got however indicates an entirely different problem. You're trying to access the user home directory from inside an unsigned applet. This has nothing to do with JSP - Applet communication.